# Why am I getting 'undefined' and empty array[] from a Promise.all call involving JavaScript async operations that use Azure APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, azure-ai

As part of my personal project that makes use of **Azure AI APIs** and **Node.js/Express,** I'm trying to respond to a *get request* to a `/viewText` route with **text** and **key phrases** extracted from an uploaded image/document.

Here's the code that should log that data to the console:

```js
app.get(`/viewText`, async (req, res) => {
  const answerReadResult = await readOperation(`${__dirname}\\uploads\\answer`);
  const markReadResult = await readOperation(`${__dirname}\\uploads\\mark`);
  
  Promise.all([
    readOperation(`${__dirname}\\uploads\\answer`),
    keyPhraseExtractor(answerReadResult),
    readOperation(`${__dirname}\\uploads\\mark`),
    keyPhraseExtractor(markReadResult),
  ]).then((data) => {
    console.log("data from Promise.all: ", data);
  });
});
```

I expected to receive two strings from the readOperation function and an array of strings from the keyPhraseExtractor, but all I get is: `data from Promise.all:  [ undefined, [], undefined, [] ]`

Here's the code for the *readOperation* function(which takes an image and returns the identifiable text as an array of strings)

```js
const readOperation = async (path) => {
  fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    files.forEach(async (file) => {
      try {
        const results = await getTextFromImage(
          `${__dirname}\\uploads\\answer\\${file}`
        );
        console.log("data from readOperation: ", results.join(" "));
        return results;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

and the log is: `data from readOperation:  you must be the change you want to see in the world !`

**N.B:** this logged data is what I'm trying to return from this function (without the *join("")*) but I'm getting *undefined* as is apparent from the *Promise.all*

The *keyPhraseExtractor* function (shown below) expects an array of strings and should return the key phrases in those strings (also as an array of strings)

```js
const keyPhraseExtractor = async (dataFromReadOperation) => {
  let results = dataFromReadOperation;
  try {
    const data = await keyPhraseExtraction(textAnalyticsClient, results);
    console.log("data inside keyPhraseExtractor: ", data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

The log is `data inside keyPhraseExtractor:  []`

Comment: Well if it catches an error, it does not return anything.

Comment: What are the logs that are above it, do you see data inside or do you see an error?

Comment: @epascarello I have shared the logs for each function below the function code and for the ``.then()`` in the ``app.get``, this is what I get ``Promise.all:  [ undefined, [], undefined, [] ]``. The **readOperation** returns *undefined* and since it's this undefined that goes into the **keyPhraseExtractor**, I believe that is why I am getting an *empty array* from the **keyPhraseExtractor**. Part of my ask, hence, is how to get the **readOperation** to return **results** (which should be an array of strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readOperation` is wrong. Within the `async` function you're kicking off `readDir` and passing it a callback, but nothing in the `async` function waits for the callback value (so `readDir` is likely not done by the time it returns), and there's no `return` in `readOperation`, so it absolutely returns `undefined`.

Yes, you have `return results`, but that's within the `forEach` `async` arrow function. There's nothing that would pass that out to the enclosing promise that `readOperation` returns.

```js
// This is not async, because it's returning a new Promise anyway.
const readOperation = /* NOT ASYNC */ (path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);       // Outer. Don't forget to stop here.
      }

      // Resolve the outer promise with an inner promise
      // from Promise.all, so getTextFromImage can run in
      // parallel. Also use `map` instead of `forEach` so the
      // return value is an array of Promises (due to the async).
      resolve(Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
        try {
          const results = await getTextFromImage(
            `${__dirname}\\uploads\\answer\\${file}`
          );
          console.log("data from readOperation: ", results.join(" "));
          return results.join(" "); // each file's return should
                                    // be a string, right?
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);  // Inner.
          throw err;           // Re-throw so it rejects the promise.
        }
      })));
    });
  });
};
```

That said, I'd suggest using the [`fs` Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api) so you're not mixing err-first callback APIs and `async` functions.

```js
// This is async, because you can await the Promises inside.
const readOperation = async (path) => {
  let files;
  try {
    files = await fsPromises.readdir(path);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);  // Outer.
    throw err;
  }
  // Still use Promise.all here, so the mapping can happen in parallel.
  // You could await this, but async functions that return Promises will
  // unwrap the results anyway: it only affects where rejections come from.
  return Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
    try {
      const results = await getTextFromImage(
        `${__dirname}\\uploads\\answer\\${file}`
      );
      console.log("data from readOperation: ", results.join(" "));
      return results.join(" ");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);  // Inner.
      throw err;           // Re-throw so it rejects the promise.
    }
  });
};
```